# How to compare if two contour paths are visually similar - Python / Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, comparison, contour

I wondering how to compare if two paths of a contour overlap, if they are similar.

To be more specific, I have a set of **n** realizations, each one with its contour levels. I need to verify the stability of each contour at level **l**. To do so, I have to count how many times it has occur through the ensambles.

So far, I was working on this code:

```
def iso_contours(scalar_fields):

    #TODO : access the paths by level (0, 1, 2 ...)
    default = 0
    contours = {}
    contours_number = 0
    for scalar_field in scalar_fields:
        cs = plt.contour(scalar_field)
        for collection in cs.collections:
            paths = collection.get_paths()
            for path in paths:
                num = contours.get(path, default)
                contours[path] = num + 1
                contours_number += 1

    contours.update((x, y/float(contours_number)) for x, y in contours.items())
    return contours
```

However, even with two equal paths, they were treated as different.

So, **I'm wondering how, given two paths, I can determine if they are visually similar**. 
As @unutbu remind me, I can not just compare vertices, because the vertices could come in a different order, or there could be a 1000 verts in one path and 100 in the other...

Comment: 1) draw the paths (AA might even help here) 2) grab the AGG buffer 3) take the inner product between the two images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I assume here that you know that your contours are plotted to the same scale and are not translated, so this isn't so much a problem of image matching as trying to find the difference between two awkward shapes.

There are several ways to do this, both of which should give roughly the same result.  The most accurate way is to take the inner product between the two curves, but this requires that the curves be aligned and descritized to the same resolution.  This can be done, for example, using interpolation, but it's a significant hassle.

The way I'll try it here is a shortcut, but it should give a reasonable estimate, which is to plot the area between the two curves and sum this area from the plot.  The smaller the area, the more similar the curves.  (That is, in summary, with the curves you'd use the inner product, with the images you'd use the area of the difference).

For example, starting from these contours:

[image]

We end with this plot, and the difference is the sum in the title:

[image]

Here's the code (it's a little complicated because I don't think there's a way to simply fill between two arbitrary parametrized curves, so instead I make images from each filled single contour and then subtract them):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import io
import Image

xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = -3, 6, -2, 3
delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(xmin, xmax, delta)
y = np.arange(ymin, ymax, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)

def f(a, b):
    return 10.*(a*Z2 - b*Z1)

def fill_contour(cs):
    v = cs.collections[0].get_paths()[0].vertices
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.fill(v[:,0], v[:,1], 'k')
    ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
    ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
    buf.seek(0)
    im = Image.open(buf).convert('L')
    r = np.asarray(im).astype(np.int)
    r/=max(r.flat)
    return r

figc = plt.figure()
axc = figc.add_subplot(111)
c0 = .07
cs1 = axc.contour(X, Y, f(.6 ,.7), [c0], colors='r')
cs2 = axc.contour(X, Y, f(.8, 1.2), [c0], colors='g')


figd = plt.figure()
axd = figd.add_subplot(111)
d1 = fill_contour(cs1)
d2 = fill_contour(cs2)
d = abs(d1-d2)
im = axd.imshow(d, cmap=cm.gray)
figd.colorbar(im)
axd.set_title( "sum = %i" % np.sum(d.flat))

figc.show()
figd.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! Pretty simple will thought and demonstration. Thank you very much. (:

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.axis('off')
```

to the fill_contour() callback will improve the results, as the axis and "dead" space is removed from the data gathered in: `fig.savefig(buf, format = 'png')`. I am trying to use this method to get the overlapping area of two contours or contourf, by doing `d = abs(d1+d2)` instead, but I'm not that pleased as I loss the X and Y information.